# Why are 'render start' and 'im being rendered' logged twice on the first render in this React component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
function App() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const previousInputValue = useRef("");

  console.log('render start')

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("im being rendered")
    previousInputValue.current = inputValue;
  }, [inputValue]);

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
      />
      <h2>Current Value: {inputValue}</h2>
      <h2>Previous Value: {previousInputValue.current}</h2>
    </>
  );
}
export default App
```

[image: result]

i was expecting that both **render start** and **im being rendered** to be logged once ,each of them

Comment: Sounds like StrictMode: https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode

Comment: Because you're in dev mode and React will double-render as a sign to you that you've doing something wrong like modifying your component (or in this case, modifying the ref) in an effect, which exist specifically to [work with things _external_ to React](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#connecting-to-an-external-system).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The react app is running in strict mode. If you comment the strict mode inside the `index.js` file then you'll only see the comments once.
This feature is helpful during the development phase of an application as it helps the developer to find bugs or side effects when the app renders.

Official documentation link to know more information regarding this: https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects